# How to create user module at run-time?

Tags: module, julia

I have different set of math expressions that must be evaluated at run-time. Currently the task is done by replacing symbols with equivalent values and `eval` the result. (could be done by any existing symbolic packages)

Now, refer to the definition of modules in Julia-lang:

> Modules in Julia are separate variable workspaces, i.e. they introduce
>   a new global scope .... Modules allow you to create top-level definitions (aka
>   global variables) without worrying about name conflicts when your code
>   is used together with somebody else’s.

And with the power of Julia to do meta-things,
I'm wondering if it is possible to create anonymous modules at run-time `m=Module()`, and use them as a scope to evaluate expressions `eval(m, :(a+b))`.
But I simply can't find a way to load variable into the run-time modules. 
Although I could get result with:

```
julia> ex=:(module mo; a=1; b=4; end)
julia> eval(ex)
julia> eval(mo,:(a+b))
```

I prefer more functional way, using anonymous modules.
Any Help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This works:

```
julia> m=Module()
anonymous

julia> eval(m, :(a=5))
5

julia> m.a
5

julia> eval(m, :(a))
5   

julia> eval(m, :(2a))
10
```